# Query taking time on production

Tags: sql, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

We have this query where we are trying to identify customers with multiple credit option indicators. This query output we have to reflect in our report and share to business users. We have to run this query almost every week and this query takes time.

Query

```
select CUST_ID, CUST_COUNT from (
SELECT N.CONS_ID AS CUST_ID,
COUNT(DISTINCT(case when M.CO_ID is null then 1 else m.co_id end)) AS CUST_COUNT
FROM CTS_VIEW.CNSLD_CREDIT_SUM M
INNER JOIN  CTS_VIEW.LEGACY_CODE_XREF  N
ON M.EE_ID = N.EE_GBL_IND
WHERE M.PROD_DT >= DATE '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY N.CONS_ID
  ) a
where CUST_COUNT>1;
```

Is there any better way to write this query that can speed up the execution time.
We have already applied the CBO and enabled vectorization at the session level.

Comment: Your query is referring to views.  That is probably the cause of the performance issue.

Comment: plase provide EXPLAIN output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query can be more speed with temp table like this. At the same time, you should check index necessary for these tables.

```
SELECT N.CONS_ID AS CUST_ID,
COUNT(Distinct(Isnull(M.CO_ID,1))) AS CUST_COUNT
Into #Temp
FROM CTS_VIEW.CNSLD_CREDIT_SUM M
INNER JOIN  CTS_VIEW.LEGACY_CODE_XREF  N
ON M.EE_ID = N.EE_GBL_IND
WHERE M.PROD_DT >= DATE '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY N.CONS_ID

select CUST_ID, CUST_COUNT from 
#Temp
where CUST_COUNT>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon CTE or Common Table Expressions will be good for these purposes -

```
SELECT CUST_ID,CUST_COUNT FROM (
WITH M_RAW_CTE AS 
(SELECT CO_ID,EE_ID,PROD_DT FROM CTS_VIEW.CNSLD_CREDIT_SUM),
M_CTE AS 
(SELECT * FROM M_RAW_CTE WHERE PROD_DT >= DATE '2018-12-31'), 
N_CTE AS 
(SELECT CONS_ID,EE_GBL_IND FROM LEGACY_CODE_XREF) 

SELECT N_CTE.CONSID AS CUST_ID,
COUNT(DISTINCT(ISNULL(M.CO_ID,1))) AS CUST_COUNT
INNER JOIN N_CTE ON M_CTE.EE_ID = N_CTE.EE_GBL_IND
GROUP BY N_CTE.CONS_ID)
WHERE CUST_COUNT > 1;
```

the concept behind using CTE's is to increase the Re-usability of data in a DDL.